# Why is maven always looking for pom.xml?

Tags: maven

Today I've started my adventure with maven and of course there are lots of problems. First of all I went through the tutorial and created the basic project, then I've created second one. I've deleted both and now is my problem. I can't do nothing now from command line. I always get error that it can't find pom.xml. 
When I type mvn clean, mvn clean install, when I create new project. Always I get building failure cause of no pom.xml

It looks like it is stuck. What can I do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The POM.xml file is actually maven's equivalent of a build file or a makefile. The pom tells maven what you actually want it to do, so it's not going to be able to build or clean without that file. See [this tutorial](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) for move info on getting started with maven.

Comment: I`ve done this tutorial. And as I said I can`t do this: mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false -> cause he can`t find pom.xml. Shouldn`t he create one with a project ? And he saying that there is now pom.xml when I want to do: mvn clean install ?

Comment: @Fixus Thanks for clarifying. Yes, that command should generate a pom for you. I've tried it on my machine and it works fine. Can you copy and paste your command and maven's output from your terminal? (Also, you're running your maven commands from the my-app directory, correct?)

Comment: hmm i wanted to get the output and it started to download everything....I can`t explain it o.O I`ll keep you guys informed

Comment: @Fixus That's a good sign. The first time you use any maven plugin, it has to download that plugin and all of its dependencies.

Comment: ok...I just can`t belive it. The problem was uber powerShell from microsoft. In normal command line it works great. Sorry for wasting your time

Comment: Just wanted to add for those, who might be looking: using PowerShell, git-bash, cmder or the likes sometimes confuses Maven so much that it starts not working properly.